# react-redux passing parameters to a sibling component

Tags: react-redux

I have a layout component that every main view is contained within. The layout view has a child component that accepts a parameter, a callback function:

```
const Layout = props => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Header onBack={props.onBack} />
    {props.children}
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

and a sample main view:

```
const Profile = props => (
  <Layout onBack={ this.onBack } >
    <div>page contents</div>
  </Layout>
)
```

I do not like passing a parameter to a parent just to pass it to a another child, it seems complicated and *IMO* antipattern. I have set up a redux store with proper reducers... but does it make sense to call an action, like setOnBack(myBackHandler) to update the store state, and in the Header component it just reads the store state? How does redux test functions in its store when it makes the diff to decide on a state change?

Answer (score 0):

What i would propose, is to separate the implementation of these handlers from your presentational component into a different file named HeaderContainer.js. Instead of using the `<Header/>` component directly in your `<Layout/>` component, you can now use the `<HeaderContainer/>` component.

**Layout.js**

```
import HeaderContainer from './HeaderContainer';

const Layout = (props) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <HeaderContainer/>
    {props.children}
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

**HeaderContainer.js**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Header from './Header.js'

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onBack: () => dispatch({ type: 'BACK_BUTTON_CLICKED' })
}) 

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

The onBack handler is now exposed as prop to the presentational component. Please note you can also use a library like recompose if you would like to use local state, or use the new React hooks API (with caution). This is still very new and not ready for production.